# Is there any way to mask appKeys/passwords from [Jenkin] console for security purpose?

Tags: karate

We have a good number of API Automation test cases running in lower environments with the Karate framework, and now we need to run all scenarios In  Prod.

As of now, Karate has amazed us with its capabilities, but now We are facing a security issue.

When we are running scenarios with Jenkins, then in the Jenkins console, in the request body, we are showing the app key.

We want to mask the app key which we sent from the request body header from the console.

Is there a way to do it from the logback-test.xml file or any other alternate approach?

The Karate version which we are using is 0.9.6.

Below is one sample request:

```
  1 > GET "URL"
  1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
  1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
  1 > Host: qa-content.api.platts.com
  1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/1.8.0_261)
  1 > appkey: **"appkeyValue"**

  07:39:31.636 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 36.58
  1 < 200
  1 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  1 < Connection: keep-alive
```

**What I did so far:**

I have added the DemoLogModifier java class in my project and in my feature file, I am calling it as (Added these 2 lines only) :

Java class URL; https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/headers/DemoLogModifier.java

```
 * def LM = Java.type('allEndPoints.DemoLogModifier')
 * configure logModifier = new LM()
```

But still, it's printing everything in the console.

Any lead/any help would be appreciated.

Edit -1: My feature file now looks like this:

```
Feature: Validate API metadata behavior

  Background:

    * def LM = Java.type('allEndPoints.DemoLogModifier')
    * configure logModifier = new LM()

  Scenario: Validate that API is responding 200 ok response with the correct  id
    Given url baseURL -> Reading from config file
    And path abc -> Reading from config file
    And param highlight = true
    And header appkey = APIappKey -> Reading from config file (This value 
    need to mask)
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

In Java class, I have not done any change.

Comment: sorry I have nothing else to offer other than the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#log-masking - follow this process if you can: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I read the doc and after that, I added the DemoLogModifier.java. I don't know, what needs to add in the feature file to replace the header value with a masked value. I believe it can be done, it looks like I am not getting the document example.

Comment: @PeterThomas I have added my feature file snippet. Can you please have a look once? I believe I am missing something, because, I am not doing anything in the header parameter to get its value changed, except adding the java calling 2 lines in feature file.

Comment: sorry again, unless I can see all the code. maybe you should just do `configure report = false` for this file and see if that works

Comment: Can we use “configure report = false” for individual steps also? If yes, how?

Comment: not for individual steps - but you can move that step into a called feature and tag it as `@report=false`

Comment: I tried but unfortunately, appkey comes in request headers after the get call. So, it's still printing in the console.

Comment: that does it. sorry - time for you to contribute code if needed or wait for someone else to answer this

Comment: I am able to mask it with the help of log file regex change. But I am surprised, that in HTML report, it's still coming.